# Printing uninitialized indices of array gives non-zero

Tags: c

i am trying to recreate the example `7.1` in `c programming by stephen kochen`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int values[10];
  int index;

  values[0]=197;
  values[2]=-100;
  values[5]=350;
  values[3]=values[0]+values[5];
  values[9]=values[5]/10;
  --values[2];

  for(index=0;index<10;++index)
    printf("values[%i] = %i \n",index,values[index]);
  return 0;
}
```

the expected output should be

```
values[0] = 197
values[1] = 0
values[2] = -101
values[3] = 547
values[4] = 0
values[5] = 350
values[6] = 0
values[7] = 0
values[8] = 0
values[9] = 35
```

but the output i was receiving is same except for he value of `values[8]` are not matching. the value i was receiving is `values[8] = 1501817896`. i couldn't figure out why?

Since there seems like a little bit of confusion. this is the output i am receiving

```
values[0] = 197
values[1] = 0
values[2] = -101
values[3] = 547
values[4] = 0
values[5] = 350
values[6] = 0
values[7] = 0
values[8] = 1501817896
values[9] = 35
```

Comment: no, there's no confusion, as far as I can tell. There's nothing said about values of variables you don't initialize. They can be 0 or anything else. I'd be extremely careful with any text that doesn't mention that and simply assumes they'd be 0 – the author at least wasn't very careful. Also, he wasn't using a compiler with high warning level to test his code examples, or he would have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized `values[8]` and few more (and they hold indeterminate value).

**Why is it bad**

C99 section 6.7.8 Initialization:

> If an object that has **automatic storage** duration is **not** initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

section 3.18 Undeﬁned behavior:

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct, of
>   erroneous data, or of **indeterminately valued** objects, for which this
>   International Standard imposes no requirements.

So accessing uninitialized values is [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in `C` and may print any value or may trap.

**Fix**

1. Change your declaration as:

   ```
   int values[10] = {0};
   ```
2. Explicitly initialize all uninitialized values.
3. Move your array to global scope or make it `static`.

Comment: Thank you. but why would i receiving `0's` for other uninitialized values except `values[8]` ?

Comment: @buggenerator as I said in my answer: luck.

Comment: @buggenerator Undefined behavior includes getting the expected results to crashing your system doing even worse things.

Comment: As @MarcusMüller said bad luck. Sometimes beginners get zero for uninitialized values and they build an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @MohitJain I just read your comment and realized it's not *actually undefined behaviour* (i.e. no crashes or undefined jumps or so), but the values are undefined; an important difference (for example, if you remember the Debian/key generation debacle of a while ago).

Comment: @MarcusMüller It may have trap representation on some platforms.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Updated answer from C specs

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing `values`; you're just using it. That is undefined behaviour, no matter what the author claims, and hence, you can't make any assumptions about `values[8]`, which you don't set.

---

**EDIT**

It's not truly undefined behaviour (that would include crashing etc), but the value you get from an uninitialized variable is simply non-deterministic.

In your case, that means that your program won't crash (because it's not accessing memory that's not there), but the output for the indices where you did not set a value are not deterministic.

Comment: but the output is was receiving for every other uninitialized values are 0. like as follows

values[0] = 197
values[1] = 0
values[2] = -101
values[3] = 547
values[4] = 0
values[5] = 350
values[6] = 0
values[7] = 0
values[8] = 1501817896
values[9] = 35

Comment: doesn't matter. It's undefined, so you might get `0`, but you might get anything else.

Comment: That is the nature of undefined behaviour... It may do one thing many times, and do something completely different unexpectedly.

Comment: alright thanks guys. so it doesn't matter how many times i receive `0`. that makes sense. @OscuroAA @Marcus Muller

Answer (score 0):

Use this to see why this happens.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  //int values[10] = {0};
  int values[10];
  int index;
  for(index=0;index<10;++index)
    printf("values[%i] = %i \n",index,values[index]);

  values[0]=197;
  values[2]=-100;
  values[5]=350;
  values[3]=values[0]+values[5];
  values[9]=values[5]/10;
  --values[2];

  for(index=0;index<10;++index)
    printf("values[%i] = %i \n",index,values[index]);
  return 0;
}
```

On my machine I get the following...

```
values[0] = 0 
values[1] = 0 
values[2] = 0 
values[3] = 0 
values[4] = 0 
values[5] = 0 
values[6] = 0 
values[7] = 0 
values[8] = 1553679856 
values[9] = 32767 
values[0] = 197 
values[1] = 0 
values[2] = -101 
values[3] = 547 
values[4] = 0 
values[5] = 350 
values[6] = 0 
values[7] = 0 
values[8] = 1553679856 
values[9] = 35
```

My `values[8]` is also not set to `0`. This is because C does not zero value arrays on allocation. To do that you can use this

```
int values[10] = {0};
```

of if it's a dynamic array use

```
int values = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
```

Many man years of debugging time has been spent on these sorts of issues.